# Is it possible for me to calculate a multiplication between two vectors with non numerical elements in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

Recently I have been using numpy's .cross function to multiply vectors. However, the function doesn't support non-numerical elements for the arrays, i.e a=[5t,6,0]. I was wondering if it was possible to, in Python, calculate such operations with maybe another function, or another method. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you want to do symbolic calculation... try sympy?

Comment: `5t` isn't a valid variable. Sometimes numpy calculations work if the arrays are object dtype, and the objects themselves have methods that support basic math like + and *.  I don't know if `cross` is such a case.

Comment: What *is* `5t`? Is it a string, some amount with unit, or something else? What would multiplying it in isolation do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with SymPy module of Python.

```py
import sympy
t = sympy.symbols('t')
a = sympy.Matrix([5*t,6,0])
b = sympy.Matrix([8*t**2, 3, 5])
print(a.cross(b))
```

Output:

```
Matrix([
[             30],
[          -25*t],
[-48*t**2 + 15*t]])
```